# Avoiding electrical shocks/statics

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought a MacBook Pro mid-2012 non-retina from the previous owner.

Some parts of my MacBook like the top-left most area of the touch pad will get me electric shocks when I touch it.

At my living room downstairs, it kind of makes we want to drop my macbook. If feels like someone flicks my finger.

At my room upstairs, it feels like being bitten by an ant or something small with sharp appendages.

What do you guys do to prevent this?

A friend suggests buying original power adapter but I'm unsure how to verify if my current adapter is original.

Comment: Please add the intensity of the electrical shock: more like a tickling, touching a door handle (and the wrong combination of shoes/carpet) with a real discharge or bathing with a hairdryer?

Comment: If you're actually getting electric shocks while using your computer then you should have it checked out by a qualified technician to determine exactly where the issue lies!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where my Mac Mini Late 2011 was giving me vibrations when I run my fingers over the aluminum part of the body - also known as "humming current". This type of current is very feeble and does not result in any shock to the body or cause any harm to the hardware components. But it is annoying. I zero-ed in on the faulty grounding of the electrical outlet. I had to run an extra grounding wire to discharge extra / spiked voltage from my power outlet into the fan loop made of iron in my ceiling. After that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem several years ago. It was suggested that I use the Power Adapter Extension Cable with the power cable as it has a 3 prongs and goes to ground. That did solve my problem.

Comment: I'm using 3-pin adapter